# moving D8 from one sub-folder to another

Tags: migrations

If you move your Drupal 8 website from one sub-folder (example.com/oldsite) of your domain to another sub-folder (example.com/newsite), you will find that internal links to pages and references to images are not updated. Instead, these links and references will point to your old domain name. How to fix this issue?

[image]

For example, this is one of the pages after the move the site from one subfolder to another. If I click on any of this links it's taking me back to the old website.

Thanks

Comment: This just seems like content to me - you’d have to update all that content yourself or you could script it if you know how to code.

Comment: Hi, @Kevin you think this module could help in this case? https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic

Answer (score 1):

I had to update the content links manually. I learned that for to create any link for the internal content i need to use relative links instead of an absolute link.

Thank You

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/103804)

Comment: @Adrien I have followed what Kevin suggested in the above comment. I updated all links manually.